# Angular service method getting undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I'm getting below issue while calling the service

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    AppInitService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initializeApp,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true
     }
]
```

app.initializer.ts

```
import { AppInitService } from './services/app-init.service';

export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitService): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    appInitService.getInit().then((res) => {
      resolve(res);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    })
    })
}
```

app-init.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async getInit(){
    return await firstValueFrom(this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
  }

}
```

I'm not able to find why getting this issue

```
main.ts:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInit')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the arrow function and pass `initializeApp` directly (that way your function will receive `AppInitService` as argument) :

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initializeApp,
  deps: [AppInitService],
  multi: true
 }
```